# how to make multiple sound augmented reality in 1 scene UNITY?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my case :-
I will make multiple sound augmented reality in 1 scene UNITY , but now i just can make only 1 sound in a scene Unity :-

I make it at AR Camera with Audio Source

and sound scrip:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DolSound : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target2; 
    public AudioSource suaradol; 

    void Start () {

    }

    void Update(){
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){ 
                if(hit.transform == target2){
                    suaradol.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play(); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Please teach me step and script to make multiple sound augmented reality in 1 scene UNITY

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For multiple sounds you have to have more multiple `AudioSource`, assign `AudioClip` to them and play them one by one

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Hamza Hasan, you need to have more than just one Audiosource and assign Audioclips to all of them. It is not possible to have one audiosource play several different clips at the same time, since it can only have one clip linked to it at one time.